# Lumen: print custom config return NULL

Tags: laravel, config, lumen

I placed the configuration directory in the application root:

/config/app.php

Contents of /config/app.php:

```
<?php

return [
    'test' => 'this config should work',
];
```

In the /bootstrap/app.php:

```
$app->configure('app');
```

To test:

```
dd(config('app.test'));
```

Result is NULL :(. How can I fix it? 
I see that there is the same issue on github (https://github.com/laravel/lumen-framework/issues/107) but I have already updated my Lumen at the last version.

Comment: I have just installed a clean Lumen to replicate it, but it works for me. I put the `$app->configure('app');` completely at the bottom of `/bootstrapp/app/php`, **right before** `return $app` though. Then in a route or controller I return `return config('app.test');` and it outputs "this config should work".

Comment: Thanks Ciccio! I tried also in a fresh clean lumen app and it works correctly. I think I have some problem so with Heroku, only in it I have NULL as result :/

Comment: But where exactly were you printing the config content? It will work _inside_ of a route (meaning, in a callback), not outside, because 'routes/web.php' loads before 'boostrap/app.php'. I'm just saying this for future readers, because I was confused about this myself. And that was the issue.

Answer (score 4):

In your bootstrap.php file add this

```
collect(scandir(__DIR__ . '/../config'))->each(function ($item) use 
($app) {
        $app->configure(basename($item, '.php'));
});
```

Answer (score 0):

I added following lines just before **return $app;** (this includes all files placed in **config** directory.

```
/*
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
| Include all configs (by SK)
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
|
| Here we include all php files that exists in config directory
|
*/
$files = scandir("config/");
if($files) {
    foreach($files as $file) {
        if(preg_match("@(\.php)$@",$file)) {
            // include app configs
            $app->configure($file);
        }
    }
}
```