# Lumen : use config constant file from other folder

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, lumen

I have laravel and lumen running parallel on a server.
and structure is like

```
var/www/application/laravel
var/www/application/lumen
```

Now laravel app is already developed for full fledged website. And lumen folder is being used for webservices. Now there are many constant files in `config` folder like `config>messages.php` and I want to reuse those without rewriting it in lumen. But currently all I can see is I can access only lumen constants in lumen, cant access laravel constant file.

Such as `config('messages.status');`  can only access value when messages.php is in lumen.

Any idea how do I configure lumen code to include laravel config constants file too?

p.s. lumen version : 5.4, laravel version : 5.2

Thanks.

Comment: Have you tried making a symlink of the laravel config into lumens folder?

Answer (score 1):

You can load all the Laravel app configs in your Lumen by making a new config file and requiring all files like this:

```
/var/www/application/lumen/config/custom.php

<?php

$path = '../../laravel/app/config/';
$config = [];

foreach ( scandir($path) as $filename ) {
    $filePath = $path . '/' . $filename;

    if (is_file($filePath)) {
        $config += require_once $filePath;
    }
}

return $config;
```

And then you can access them in your Lumen like this `config('custom.key');`.

Answer (score 0):

That's right, there are predefined paths for configuration files. Take a look at `vendor/laravel/lumen-framework/src/Application.php`. There's a `getConfigurationPath` method there.

Basically, Lumen will try to load config files from *your* config folder, and if nothing is found then will load from `/vendor/laravel/lumen-framework/config/*`

I suggest you symlink them. As I don't see any way to modify Lumen core for this (actually, yes, you could override Application class and instantiate it in the bootstrap, but you should take care of things like the `__DIR__` constant inside it).

**UPDATE**

Maybe it's easier. Take a look at this loop: [Lumen: print custom config return NULL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35585897/lumen-print-custom-config-return-null) . The guy is loading every config file in a loop using `$app->configure($file);` method.

Actually, looks like the TheFallen solution here.